# Media Player with multiple mp3 files issue

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a piano app working with this method:

```
 public void play(String note) {
    score++;
    score();

    try {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier(note, "raw", getPackageName()));
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer media) {
                media.release();
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", "error playing file : " + note + "\n" + e);
    }

}
```

The issue is that if I press the keys too fast and several times i get errors like this:

```
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)
```

These errors occur as I go on playing. But when I uninstall the app, something seems to reset, and I get less errors...Why is this happening and is there a solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code implies you are playing notes and not long MP3s, I suggest you use `SoundPool` instead of `MediaPlayer`. It is better suited for this kind of application as it pre-loads all the resources in advance.

An example of this kind of implementation:

```
private SoundPool soundPool;
private HashMap<String, Integer> soundNameToSoundIdMap;

private void initSoundMap() {
    soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundNameToSoundIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    soundNameToSoundIdMap.put("note_a", loadSound(getContext(), R.raw.note_a));
    soundNameToSoundIdMap.put("note_b", loadSound(getContext(), R.raw.note_b));
}

private int loadSound(Context context, int resId) {
    return soundPool.load(context, resId, 1);
}

public void play(String note) {
    score++;
    score();

    Integer soundId = soundNameToSoundIdMap.get(note);
    if (soundId != null){
        soundPool.play(soundId.intValue(), 100, 100, 1, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Doron, but i've already tried soundpool in this kind of app and one note "kills" the following, so you cant hear the previous sound untill the end... anyway, i've added a permition to my manifest and it seems its working better so far...

Comment: SoundPool can play multiple steams at the same time (have a look at setMaxStreams()), I guess you initialized it with only max steams = 1. I still think it is probably the better option for you from a performance perspective as you don't need to load a note before you play it.

Comment: Ok, guess you're right, but i'm on a tight schedule...i guess the next time i'll try soundpool